# Android "Can't Play Video" after repeat it for several hours

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an application that repeats a video in flash card. It is working and play the video for several hours but then the player crash (and some times the Android system freezes too) while showing the message "Can't Play Video".

So its not a problem about the file or format because it plays the video.
Could be a problem from the Android platform (I'm using 2.1 App) ?

There is any way I could catch this error and restart again the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `VideoView` or a `MediaPlayer` you can register a listener via the `setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener l)`
then you can implement the `public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)` and handle the errors there